# Storing the amount of factors as a variable in C

Tags: c

I'm taking a beginner's programming course and have a question. I'm suppose to be able to enter a number, and have it print out something like this

```
Factors of 36 between 2 and 35: 2 3 4 6 9 12 18 
36 has 7 factors
36 is not a prime number
```

My code so far allows the user to enter a number, and can print out the first line, but i'm having trouble getting the number of factors as a variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int num, num2, factors;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    num2 = num - 1;
    printf("Factors of %d between 2 and %d: ", num, num2);
    for(factors = 2; factors < num; factors++){
        if(num % factors == 0){
            printf("%d ",factors);
            }
        }
    if(num % factors == 0){
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d has factors\n", num);
        printf("%d is not a prime number\n", num);}
}
```

If I can figure out how to get number of factors as a variable, then I can get the third line by myself, but I'm having trouble.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Add another `int` variable, initialize it to zero, and increment it whenever you find a factor

Comment: So you currently loop from 2 to num, and in that loop check if `factors` is a factor. Create a new variable, set to 2 (or zero depending on how you count) then increment it whenever you find and print a factor.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how to store all factors?

However, based on your sample output, you wouldn't even need to cache the values, you should only need to keep a count of them.

Initialize a variable `cnt` to 0

```
int cnt = 0;
```

and increment it every time you see a factor:

```
  if(num % factors == 0){
      printf("%d ",factors);
      cnt++;
  }
```

Then your line 2 output would be:

```
printf("%d has %d factors", num, cnt);
```

And then you can check the cnt of factors to determine if it is prime:

```
bool isPrime = (cnt == 0);
if(isPrime) printf("%d is a prime number", num);
else printf("%d is not a prime number", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm error

The `for()` has no early `break`, so after the loop is done, `factors == num` if `num` is at least 2.

```
for(factors = 2; factors < num; factors++){
....
}
// This is really doing `num % num` which is 0, which equals 0, so always true
if(num % factors == 0){
```

Instead simply counts the factors.  2nd half similar to [@James Wierzba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36184099/2410359)

```
unsigned count = 0;
for(factors = 2; factors < num; factors++) {
  if(num % factors == 0){
    count++;
    printf("%d ",factors);
  }
}

if (count > 0) {
  printf("%d is not a prime number\n", num);}
}
```